# Executing bitmask with elastics database query

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch

I would like to select data from an elastics database where the data it returns will be based on the (bitmap) evaluation of a number in the query. 
Something like $x & 32 == 32

The query is as follows:

```
{
  "size":1000,
  "sort": {
    "timestamp": "desc"
  },
  "fields" : ["id","timestamp", "eval_id"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": "450"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {"eval_id": "161"}
        },
        {
              "range": {
                "timestamp": {
                  "gte": 1427061600000,
                  "lte": 1427147999000
                }
              }
            }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So the "eval_id" must pass a bitmap evaluation in order to be returned by the JSON result.

So eval_id can be 161 or 681 or 421 and so on..

In SQL it looks like this: SUM(If ((eval_id & 1 = 1), 1,0)) as 'EVAL_value'

Can anyone help?